# Getting Intellij IDEA to process GWT RequestFactory annotations

Tags: gwt, annotations, intellij-idea, requestfactory

Having upgraded to GWT 2.4.0, I want (need) to enable [annotation processing](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/RequestFactory_2_4) for my RequestFactory interfaces. The [instructions](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/RequestFactoryInterfaceValidation) for doing that in Eclipse are clear enough, but I can't find the corresponding instructions for Intellij IDEA.

The fields of the [annotation processing settings](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/settings.png) page in Intellij seem to require a 'Processor FQ Name', whatever that is. What might that be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that one does not have to enable the annotation processor. Once I had all of the right JAR files in the classpath (requestfactory-apt and requestfactory-server in this case), and removed an old version of gwt-servlet.jar from the classpath, and invalidated Intellij's caches, and removed previously-compiled versions of my project, and restarted Intellij, and held my mouth in just the right position, the annotation processor ran, even though I had 'Enable annotation processing' unchecked.

Comment: I think you forgot the part about sacrificing a live chicken under a full moon at midnight.

Answer (score 1):

I assume "Processor FQ Name" is a fully qualified class name (class name and package) to a class that processes annotations.

Answer (score 1):

There are some instructions for IntelliJ here:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UASaSSrGFJOmRPC7NCeEqabSGoNmyEs4Ir-4H1y1a6g/edit?hl=en_US

The Processor FQ name should be: `com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.apt.RfValidator`